# JQuery is not recognised after an AJAX call, event after using delegates

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my code which even after using Delegates, doesnt work after an ajax page load.

```
$(function () {
        $(document).on('focus', '[placeholder]', (function () {
            .....            
         })).on('blur', (function () {
               ...
         })).blur();

        $('[placeholder]').parents('form').on('submit', (function () {
            $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
                .....                    }
            })
        }));
    });
```

I am not sure i have used delegates in a proper manner. Please suggest!

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console, that might stop JavaScript from working overall?

Comment: I see a lot of extra `(` and `)`

Comment: Parenthesis are not extra. That i checked.

Comment: No errors in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

You are not delegating to form submit:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', (function () {
            $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
                .....                    }
            })
        }));
```

Comment: Even removing that submit part, doesnt recognize "$".